# Breaking Down my money

Tags: c

Can anybody help me with my code? my program shows wrong output, when i try to enter the number 2880 it shows 'Invalid Input'. the number 2880 is divisible by 20 right ? why does it go Invalid

```
int money, x[6],y[6],total;

x[0] = 1000; x[1] = 500; x[2] = 200; x[3] = 100; x[4] = 50; x[5] = 20;

system("cls");
printf("Enter your Money: ");
scanf("%d", &money);

total = money;

printf("\nBreakdown:\n");

for(int i=0;i < 6; i++){

    y[i] = ( money - (money % x[i]) )/x[i];
    money = (money % x[i]);

   if (y[i] != 0)
    printf("%10d  x  %d  =  %5d \n",x[i], y[i], (x[i] * y[i]));

}

printf("---------------------------\n");
printf("Total:                %d",total);

if(money>0){
   system("cls");
printf("Invalid Input !");

}
getch();
```

i am expecting my output will be like this:

```
Enter your Money: 2880

Breakdown:
      1000  x  2  =   2000
       500  x  1  =    500
       200  x  1  =    200
       100  x  1  =    100
        20  x  4  =     80
---------------------------
Total:                2880
```

Comment: What is the output you *actually* get? Have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code line by line?

Comment: your algorithm is too greedy, it divides 80 to 50+20 then leave 10 unhandled, rather than dividing it into 20x4

Comment: There is something wrong with your algorithm. You end up with 30$, not 80$, hence.

Comment: if(money>0){
   system("cls");
printf("Invalid Input !");  // if there is a remainder 'Invalid Input' will apears

Comment: so there a remainder 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `if` clause in your `for` loop to ignore division by 50$ if the money is a multiple of 20, if that is what you actually want.

Otherwise, your program is doing exactly what you want it to do.

```
int money () {
    int money, total;

    int x[6] = { 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20 };
    int y[6] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    printf("Enter your money: ");
    scanf("%d", &money);

    total = money;

    printf("\nBreakdown:\n");

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        if (x[i] == 50 && money % 20 == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        y[i] = (money - (money % x[i]))/x[i];
        money = (money % x[i]);
    }

    if (money > 0 && y[3] > 0) {
        money += 50;
        if (money % 20 == 0) {
            y[5] = money / 20;
            y[3] = y[3] - 1;
            y[4] = y[4] + 1;
            money = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
       if (y[i] != 0) {
           printf("\t  %4d  x%5d  =  %5d \n", x[i], y[i], (x[i] * y[i]));
       }
    }

    printf("\t---------------------------\n");
    printf("\t  Total:           %5d\n\n", total);

    if(money > 0) {
        printf("Invalid input!");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I have added an `if` clause for sums like `$2810` that has a remainder of 10$ (if decomposed in the standard manner) and can hence be differently decomposed. The idea is to check if by adding 50$, the remainder can be nicely divided into a number of 20$. This 50$ comes from breaking down an existing 100$.

**E.g.** 
$210 is first decomposed into: $100 x 2, and a remainder of $10, hence INVALID

So, instead, we change a $100 into 2 x $50 such that we get

$100 x 1, $50 x 1, and a remainder of $10

We sum the $50 with the remaining $10 to get $60, which is broken down into $20 x 3

Therefore, we get $210 = 1 x $100, 1 x $50, 3 x $20.

Comment: Please do not spoonfeed the asker of the question. Explain what you have changed!

Comment: @AshishAhuja I believe I have already commented and pointed out his mistake before I added this. This is for his reference AFTER he has tried out his own way. This is just ONE out of multiple possible solutions.

Comment: @AshishAhuja Also, if you have bothered to read my post, you would actually realize that I did explain what I changed at the very top. However, I did also accidentally include code for some other project, which I have since removed.

Comment: A comment is not the whole point of the post. Good that you changed the answer, but by the way, in your original post, you did not explain the changes.

Comment: @AshishAhuja I most certainly thought that I did. I may be mistaken though. I was scrambling to answer a return comment on another question. My bad. Regardless, hope everyone is happy now.

Comment: This approach is OK when the problem has hundred bills. However if the problem does not have 100 and then it would try to divide 100 into 20x5 rather than 50x2. This is good engineering but poor algorithm, aka "a hack".

Comment: sorry guys its my mistake!

Comment: @user3528438 It is most definitely a hack! If the array `x` is changed to include other denominations, this approach is very likely to fall apart. But I am not sure of what you mean when you say "However if the problem does not have 100 and then it would try to divide 100 into 20x5 rather than 50x2." Can you please clarify?

Comment: @My mistake, the condition is good enough that I can not find a fail case easily. Maybe it's a practically good enough solution.

Comment: @user3528438 OK. No problem, :). This was meant as a practical solution but not a comprehensive one. Thank you!

Comment: while (true){} what does this mean

Comment: @Star_iCe Please ignore that! Just a hack to stop my console from automatically closing after outputting the breakdown, LOL. I will remove it from my post.

Comment: @Tacocat what if the Input is 2810 it has a remainder?

Comment: @Star_iCe If the input is 2810, it would output INVALID INPUT. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @Star_iCe OK, np. Cheers!

Comment: Im pretty confuse of this, is this still divisible by 20

Enter your money: 2810

Breakdown:
      1000  x  2  =   2000
       500  x  1  =    500
       200  x  1  =    200
         50  x  1  =      50
        20   x  3  =      60
---------------------------
Total:                2810

Comment: @Star_iCe I am sorry... But I don't understand what you mean because I am not getting that!  I am getting 1000 x 2, 500 x 1, 200 x 1, 100 x 1. Which sums up to 2800. Therefore, there is a remainder of 10, and it is an invalid input. Why is yours missing 100$?

Comment: i change it to 50 x 1 & 20 x 3 to get 110 it is still divisible to int x[6] = { 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20 }; ?

Comment: @Star_iCe So, you ARE actually seeking a comprehensive solution. Give me a moment.

Comment: you probably shouldn't keep expecting TacoCat to spoonfeed you the whole comprehensive solution. This is quite comprehensive for you. It would be great if u just step through it in the IDE and slowly understand it

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I compiled this program, it worked successfully, just that the after showing the breakdown, it showed invalid input. I think you want to print invalid input when the money inputted is less than 0, as printing invalid input when money is more than 0 does not make sense. I think you should just change

```
if(money>0){
```

to

```
if(money<0){
```

Also, your breakdown is wrong, as it leaves 10 behind, and the sum just adds upto 2870 instead of 2880.

**EDIT:** You just now mentioned in your comment that you print invalid input when there is a remainder. Next time please mention that in the question, as in confuses the answerers of the question, just like I got confused. I'll get back with a solution, but I won't delete my original answer.

Comment: @Star_iCe, I got that, I'll come back.

Comment: @ Ashish Ahuja sorry i forgot

Comment: @Star_iCe, you can see tacocats answer. It is correct.